Rust diesel get id based on latest(max) Timestampz
I have the following table
diesel::table! {
    foo (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        section -> Int4,
        is_bar -> Bool,
        time -> Nullable<Timestampz>,
    }
}


I want to get the ids, that are is_bar = true, with the latest time for each section. If I'd have written it in PostgreSQL it would be something like this
create table foo (
  id integer primary key,
  section integer not null,
  is_bar bool not null,
  time timestamp with time zone
);

insert into foo values (1, 1, true, now());
insert into foo values (2, 2, true, now());
insert into foo values (3, 1, false);
insert into foo values (4, 3, false);
insert into foo values (5, 3, true, now());
insert into foo values (6, 1, true, now());

select * from foo;

select
    id
from
    foo
where
    time = (
        select
            max(time)
        from
            foo as boo
        where
            boo.is_bar = true
            and boo.section = foo.section);

with the output
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
 id | section | is_bar |             time              
----+---------+--------+-------------------------------
  1 |       1 | t      | 2024-12-19 13:51:35.940578+00
  2 |       2 | t      | 2024-12-19 13:51:35.941905+00
  3 |       1 | f      | 
  4 |       3 | f      | 
  5 |       3 | t      | 2024-12-19 13:51:35.946243+00
  6 |       1 | t      | 2024-12-19 13:51:35.947379+00
(6 rows)

 id 
----
  2
  5
  6
(3 rows)

So after some reading I tried the following code
let (t1, t2) = diesel::alias!(foo as f1, foo as f2);
let res = t1
    .filter(
        t1.field(foo::time).eq(
            t2.filter(
               t2.field(foo::is_bar).eq(true).and(
                    t2.field(foo::section).eq(t1.field(foo::section)),
               ),
            )
        ),
    )
    .select(t1.field(foo::id))
    .load::<i32>(conn)?;

and got this very long error, that ends with diesel::expression::ValidGrouping<()> is not satisfied 
next I tried
let subquery = foo::table
        .filter(foo::is_bar.eq(true))
        .select(diesel::dsl::max(foo::time))
        .group_by(foo::section);

let results = foo::table
        .filter(foo::time.eq_any(subquery))
        .select(id)
        .load::<i32>(conn)?;

and again a very long error ending with diesel::query_builder::from_clause::AsQuerySource is not satisfied on the call to eq_any
and I got about the same error for my last try, only this time on the call to on
let subquery = foo::table
        .filter(foo::is_bar.eq(true))
        .select(diesel::dsl::max(foo::time))
        .group_by(foo::section);

let results = foo::table
        .inner_join(subquery.on(foo::section.eq(foo::section)))
        .select(foo::id)
        .load::<i32>(conn)?;

how can make this query using diesel?
